# Is there functionality in IntelliJ that let us find the most referred functions or methods?

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy

I'm trying to find a way in IntelliJ IDEA to find all the usages of  method calls in a particular project, sorted descendingly from the most used methods to the least. Is that possible?

The background for finding such function is to be able to write tests for the most critical methods and functions in the project.

Comment: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/93-metricsreloaded may help.

Answer (score 0):

Just right-mouse-button and click on find-usage